# Excel - Create a Category based on array of columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large database that I would like to create a way to match a set of criteria to a name.

For a scaled example: if managing apartments with different furnishing levels (table, chair, bed), each furniture has its own column, and the apartment location would have a x in each column for the furniture it holds. 
[Example View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVu1M.png)

[image]

If managing hundreds of locations, i would like to have a table with all the options (shown in image), to be a "look up" table of sorts, and to have a formula to match the information in the cells to the lookup table, and output the "furnishing level".

I understand that this can be done with nested IF statements, however, for the actual database there are typically 20+ columns that need to be matched, thus creating large formulas with many locations for errors. I have not been able to find an elegant solution to this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a master list for Furnishing Level? How would you handle more than one items missing cases e.g. there may be 2 - 3 or even 4 items missing in the columns.

Comment: the Furnishing Level is a simplified version of the real issue, so I only made what i was hoping could be a look up table

Comment: Your example has cases where only one item is missing or only one is present or it's Fully Furnished. What if more than one item is missing, say 2 - 3 or even 4, what should Furnishing Level mention in such a case?